# Matrix has zero or negative values on diagonal

Tags: matrix, stata

I am trying in Stata to regress GRP growth rate with a variety of variables including education quality and quantity.
I have attempted to carry out a multicollinearity test on my data set

code: collin logy p s quan qual

but it is returning error 'corr(): matrix has zero or negative values on diagonal'

Does anyone have any idea how I can identify the root of the problem or ways I can get around it?

Comment: No information in the question about correlations in your dataset.

Comment: `graph matrix  p s quan qual logy` may disclose some problem. Note that `collin` should be about looking at predictor variables; don't include your response or outcome (dependent variable in ancient terminology).